# Dotnet tool install error : ''0.0.1'' is not a valid version string

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have done a clean install of Visual Studio 2022. When I try to install a global tool like this:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format
```

But I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\NuGet.targets(156,5): error : ''0.0.1'' is not a valid version string. (Parameter 'val
ue') [C:\Users\herma\AppData\Local\Temp\eaa528ac-8931-4e8a-b845-6bd7673a239d\restore.csproj]                       er 'val
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-format' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.     
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

The ''0.0.1'' seems very odd, (they are a pair of single quotes instead). I have no idea where this values comes from since I have not set it anywhere. Does anyone know where this comes from and how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

If someone ever come across a similar problem, check to see if somehow there is an environment variable named VERSION set. I had one on my system set to '0.0.1' by another unrelated tool that was being used by dotnet.